Correct capitalisation of acronym with both a class word and a hyphen
I am using package acro (version 2) to keep track of acronyms on a review paper I am writing.
I am using package mfirstuc-english to avoid capitalising class words (such as "and", "of", "to").
I am also using command \MFUhyphentrue to capitalise all parts of words with hyphens.
Acronyms that contain both a class word and a hyphen should not capitalise the class word. However, I am not able to achieve this desired outcome.
Examples of correct capitalisations I would like to have:

This and That Example. and is not capitalised. ✓
This-That Example. Both This and That are capitalised. ✓
This-and-That Example. This and That are capitalised but and is not. ✗

In the last example, though, I get "This-And-That", with a capitalised And.
Here is a MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mfirstuc-english}
\usepackage[uc-cmd=\capitalisewords]{acro}[=v2]

\MFUhyphentrue

\DeclareAcronym{bwe}{
    short = BWE,
    long = black and white example
}

\DeclareAcronym{hhe}{
    short = HHE,
    long = hyphen-hyphen example
}

\DeclareAcronym{rbe}{
    short = RBE,
    long = red-and-blue example
}

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \Ac{bwe} \\
    \Ac{hhe} \\
    \Ac{rbe}
\end{document}

Output:
Black and White Example (BWE)
Hyphen-Hyphen Example (HHE)
Red-And-Blue Example (RBE)

Desired output:
Black and White Example (BWE)
Hyphen-Hyphen Example (HHE)
Red-and-Blue Example (RBE)

Constraints:

I must use acro version 2. Version 3 is too slow for the amount of acronyms we have, and it will timeout the server where we compile the project. Even on a local machine, it is so slow that it makes it impractical to work on our large literature review.
Eventually, the file must be compiled with pdflatex, as per the journal's requirement. Xelatex, Context, Luatex, etc. are not allowed.


Can you get these capitalisations working on ordinary text outside of acro? As far as I can see this question has nothing directly to do with acro. Capitalising red-and-blue as Red-and-Blue is not supported by mfirstuc going by the examples on page 19 of the documentation.
